# SwiftUI List rows in Edit Mode do not allow Buttons actions/NavigationLinks to work?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

SwiftUI List rows in Edit Mode do not allow Buttons actions to work I note (as well as NavigationLinks too).  Is there a way to get this working?

**Goal** - Want to have NavigationLink or Modal view to the following depending on the edit mode.  This relies on the ability to have button actions/nav links working in Edit Mode.   (if there's another way to achieve my goal happy to have pointers)

1. Not Edit Mode:  Click on row => Detailed view for this record
2. In Edit Mode: Click on row => Edit view for the master record name (e.g. rename)

Code (just to highlight the button doesn't work in Edit Mode):

```
   List() {
        ForEach(gcLists) { gcList in
            HStack {
                Button(gcList.title) {
                    print("button pressed!")
                }
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteList)
        .onMove(perform: move)
    }
```

Comment: Instead of a Button you could use any View ( e.g. Text) with a onTapGesture. onTapGesture are always working.

Comment: Are there any better solutions in the meantime than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used previously the following approach, please try

```
Button(action: {}) {
  // label content here
}
.onTapGesture {
  // action here
}
```

Comment: The `onTapGesture` is only triggered if I tap the button text. Is there a way to trigger it if I tap anywhere in the list row?

Comment: @alobaili, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996185/12299030

Comment: @alobaili Put a `Rectangle()` inside. I used `.fill(.background)` because I've noticed that if you use `clear` colour, it doesn't work.