# Custom Button in SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, list, button, swiftui

[SwiftUI Custom Button in List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6bte.png)

I'm trying to create a custom button in a SwiftUI List. I want it to have a blue background with white text, and importantly, to remain blue and go to 50% opacity when pressed, not the default grey.

I tried using a custom ButtonStyle, but when I do so, the tappable area of the button is reduced to just the label itself. If I tap any other part of the cell, the colour doesn't change. If I remove the ButtonStyle, tapping anywhere on the cell works

How can I fix this so that I get my custom colours, including the colour when tapped, but the whole cell is still tappable?

```
import SwiftUI

struct BlueButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .font(.headline)
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.5) : Color.white)
        .listRowBackground(configuration.isPressed ? Color.blue.opacity(0.5) : Color.blue)
  }
}

struct ExampleView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    Text("Info")
                }

                Section {
                    Button(action: {print("pressed")})
                    {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Save")
                            Spacer()
                        }

                    }.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle())
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In standard variant List intercepts and handles content area of tap detection, in your custom style it is defined, by default, by opaque area, which is only text in your case, so corrected style is

[image: demo]

### Update for: Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

It looks like Apple broken something, because `listRowBackground` now works **only** inside `List` itself, no subview, which is senseless from generic concept of SwiftUI.

[Updated solution with same behavior as on demo](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/List_row_wide_button.md)

### Original for: Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct BlueButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .font(.headline)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.5) : Color.white)
        .listRowBackground(configuration.isPressed ? Color.blue.opacity(0.5) : Color.blue)
  }
}
```

and usage, just

```
Button(action: {print("pressed")})
{
    Text("Save")
}.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle())
```

and even

```
Button("Save") { print("pressed") }
    .buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle())
```

Comment: the `listRowBackground()` will no longer work, tested on iOS 15, any ideas how to solve? I am using it inside a `Form`

Comment: @Niklas try .background()

Comment: This is now a bit buggy in iOS 16/Xcode 14.2. The button highlight state doesn't animate all the time. @Asperi