# Is it possible to create a LazyVGrid without the Lazy modifier?

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I'm loading data in from my Firebase backend, the "lazy" part makes my app look glitchy/frozen-like when scrolling down, it lags heavily...

Is it possible to create a VGrid "without the lazy functionality"??
(iOS 14)

If not, any suggestions other than ditching the Grid look altogether?

```
let layout = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),

]

@ObservedObject var homeModel = Home_ViewModel()


NavigationView(content: {
        
        ScrollView() {
            LazyVGrid(columns: layout, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(homeModel.projectList) { item in
                    
                    ProjectItemWidget(
                        projectID: item.id,
                        projectTitle: item.projectTitle,
                        projectAuthorProfileImage: item.authorProfileImageUrl,
                        projectAuthor: item.projectAuthor)
                }
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 7.5)
        }
}
```

Comment: That probably signifies that you're doing some heavy lifting in the `init` of one of your views. The solution is more likely to change the way your grid item view behaves -- not the grid itself.

Comment: Changing the behavior? Any examples would be appreciated. Yes, I'm doing heavy lifting but it's on the server side.

Comment: When I remove the LazyGrid() and just run the ForEach() function it scrolls perfectly, it only lags with the "Lazy" part of the VGrid.

Comment: Without a [mre], it's not possible to troubleshoot what might be causing the lag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Grid/ UICollectionView with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550222/creating-a-grid-uicollectionview-with-swiftui)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling thinking in a solution where a could create a grid layout without using LazyVGrid and came up with the following:

```
extension Array {
    func getElementAt(index: Int) -> Element? {
        return (index < self.endIndex) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

struct CustomGridLayout<Element, GridCell>: View where GridCell: View {

    private var array: [Element]
    private var numberOfColumns: Int
    private var gridCell: (_ element: Element) -> GridCell
        
    init(_ array: [Element], numberOfColumns: Int, @ViewBuilder gridCell: @escaping (_ element: Element) -> GridCell) {
        self.array = array
        self.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
        self.gridCell = gridCell
    }
        
        var body: some View {
            Grid {
                ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: self.array.count, by: self.numberOfColumns)), id: \.self) { index in
                    GridRow {
                        ForEach(0..<self.numberOfColumns, id: \.self) { j in
                            if let element = self.array.getElementAt(index: index + j) {
                                self.gridCell(element)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
```

An example using in a View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var array: [Int] = Array(1...7)
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomGridLayout(array, numberOfColumns: 3) { element in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("\(element)")
                }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

You can see the result in the following link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7ip.png