# How to make List Item row with a button inside not clickable in Swift UI?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to make it so that the whole row of a list is not clickable?

I'm trying to make it so that only the button is clickable on the button row.

[image]

As you can see, if I try to click on anywhere in the button's row, whether on the button itself, or even on the white space around it, it treats it as a tap:

[image]

Is there a way to make it so that you can only click on the button itself, and not the white spacing around it? (i.e. the row itself)

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Next screen")) {
                    Text("Item")
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 12)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, in this implementation I absolutely have to put these elements in a `List`, so I don't really have any other choice (e.g. to normally use a `VStack`)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make it non-default button style, like Plain or your custom

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
       .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())  // << here !!
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996185/12299030) post for example of do similar with custom button style

Comment: It's good I can't click on the whole row now, but it won't let me click on the button. Is there a way to be able to click on the button without clicking on the white part?

Comment: I checked it initially and the button was made clickable. Is there no way right now in SwiftUI to make the space around the button unclickable whilst the button is clickable? Or is list the wrong tool to use here?

Comment: @pizzae, it just because in provided code the button is row-wide. Wrap it in VStack and make less width and it will be clickable only in button.

Comment: This works for me thank you. But why does this work? This just seems silly. How does specifying the button style to what seems like a default style change how the list cell handles touches? Am I overthinking it or is that a little cray cray?

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to one of my button's content (as you did in your example). Otherwise I could no longer click the button.