# Adding contextMenu to a Button within a List prevents default Button functionality

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to create a list with actions that occur both on tap/click and support a context menu.

Buttons do support contextMenu when outside the list (#1), but when inside the list (#2), taps are no longer recognized, though the contextMenu still works. Is this intentional?

```
struct ContextMenu: View {
    @State var on = false

    var button: some View {
        Button(action: { self.on.toggle() }) {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(on ? "on" : "off")

            // #1: works for both tap and context
            button.contextMenu {
                button
            }

            // #2: tap on button no longer works
            List {
                button.contextMenu {
                    button
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding `.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()` to the Button. This enables tapping, but only of the text, not the entire row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a question to Apple... meanwhile here is a possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
List {
    button
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .contextMenu {
            button
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.on.toggle()
        }
}
```

if you want highlight on row tap then it needs to apply custom ButtonStyle. For example you can consider solution in [Custom Button in SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996185/12299030)

Comment: Thanks - this is a useful workaround! I've created feedback for Apple as well.