# How to make a button inside a List() that is full width with colored background and clickable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Requirements:**

- I need to use a list because I'm using it with NavigationLink and I don't wish to code the list logic into a VStack

- I need a button that inside a List that has a colored background, like this

https://imgur.com/rlQh4nT

- The button needs to have the default highlight animation when touched is down and it needs to register the tap 100% of the time

**Attempt 1:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink("hi") {
                        Text("a")
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("hi") {
                        print("test")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    .tint(.pink)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.pink.opacity(0.2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks correct, but the issue is that you can only tap the word "hi", anywhere else in the row is not tappable and thus does not highlight (or action)

**Attempt 2:**

```
struct BlueButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .font(.headline)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.5) : Color.white)
        .listRowBackground(configuration.isPressed ? Color.blue.opacity(0.5) : Color.blue)
  }
}

Button(action: {print("pressed")})
{
    Text("Save")
}.buttonStyle(BlueButtonStyle())
```

Solution is taken from [Custom Button in SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995278/custom-button-in-swiftui-list) which used to work but broke again in iOS 16. It looks correct and behave correct, but the tap is only registered maybe 80% of the time.

**Attempt 3:**

```
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink("hi") {
                        Text("a")
                    }
                }

                Button(action: {
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("hi")
                    }
                })
                .tint(.pink)
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.pink.opacity(0.2))
        }
```

This is actually the first attempt (but it was 2 months ago I forgotten about this). This will NOT work because the tap will only register 50% of the time (the OS will think the other half of the time you are scrolling)

If you have a creative solution please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer after a 3 month search.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            Section {
                NavigationLink("hi") {
                    Text("a")
                }
            }
            
            //working!!
            Button(action: {}) {
                Button(action: {
                    print("hi")
                }) {
                    Text("hi")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .tint(.pink)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this approach, where you have the `frame` on the `Text`, as shown in the example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Button(action: { print("button clicked")}) {
                    Text("Button")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)  // <-- here
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)  // <-- here
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .background(.yellow)  // <-- here
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

replaced `.buttonStyle(.plain)` with `.buttonStyle(.borderless)`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, the button become unclickable

Comment: All works well for me, on MacOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
Maybe it is different on older systems. You could try adding `.buttonStyle(.plain)` to the `Button`, this works for me as well. I'll update my answer. Does **just** my code not work for you?

Comment: First of all it's weird I don't know why I can't tag you. But secondly have you found a solution yet? Your current code still doesn't work. I need entire row to be clickable not just the text. I just tested with latest xcode and iOS 16

Comment: updated my answer with removing the `.buttonStyle(.plain)`,
 for some reason this interferes with the Button tap. My (updated) answer works for me
 on real ios-16 devices and macCatalyst.
 I don't understand what you mean by `... I don't know why I can't tag you`

Comment: Tried this, does not work. Not 100% hit rate. Around 50% or less.